# Working with Tab Control - Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, tabcontrol, xamarin.android

I have following Tab control in my activity. It contains 2 tabs.

On Click of `Tab`, it should navigate to a new `activity`.

But I'm having 2 issues with it.

**1.)** it is giving me `IllegalArgumentException` when following code is used :

```
    TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabHost);
            tabHost.Setup();

    TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 1");
            spec1.SetContent(Resource.Id.tab1);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity1));
            spec1.SetContent(i);
            spec1.SetIndicator("Tab 1");

    TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 2");
            spec2.SetContent(Resource.Id.tab2);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(Activity2));
            spec2.SetContent(i);
            spec2.SetIndicator("Tab 2");

        tabHost.AddTab(spec1);
        tabHost.AddTab(spec2);
```

**2.)** and for demo purpose , I tried this simple code :

```
TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabHost);
 tabHost.Setup(); 

TabHost.TabSpec spec1=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 1");
spec1.SetContent(Resource.Id.tab1);
spec1.SetIndicator("Tab 1");

TabHost.TabSpec spec2=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Tab 2");
spec2.SetContent(Resource.Id.tab2);
spec2.SetIndicator("Tab 2");

tabHost.AddTab(spec1);
tabHost.AddTab(spec2);
```

But it this case, `Tab` is **always taking the focus**.

i.e. I have a `EditText` in my activity and as soon as I try to type something in it, focus goes to `Tab`.

I have no idea why this is happening, any solution?

I'm absolute beginner to mono for android, so any help appreciated..

### EDIT

Considering the suggestions, I used this :

```
TabHost.TabSpec spec;     
        Intent intent;

TabHost tabHost=(TabHost)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tabHost);
                tabHost.Setup();

            intent = new Intent (this, typeof (HeatMap));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            spec=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Heat Map");
            spec.SetIndicator("Heat Map");
            spec.SetContent(intent);
            tabHost.AddTab(spec);

            intent = new Intent (this, typeof (LiveMkt));
            intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

            spec=tabHost.NewTabSpec("Live Mkt");
            spec.SetIndicator("Live Mkt");
            spec.SetContent(intent);
            tabHost.AddTab(spec);
```

But I got this error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Did you forget to call 'public void setup(LocalActivityManager activityGroup)'?    
android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:649)     
android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:323)
android.widget.TabHost.addTab(TabHost.java:213)
stockgadget.controls.HeatMap.n_onCreate(Native Method)
stockgadget.controls.HeatMap.onCreate(HeatMap.java:25)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem is for your second example.

But in the first example, I think your problem is that you are setting the Tab Content twice - e.g.:

```
        spec1.SetContent(Resource.Id.tab1);
```

and

```
        spec1.SetContent(i);
```

Just set the content once - either to a subtab defined in the layout XML or to a dynamically created activity - not both.

A good place to start is the ApiDemo in https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples - e.g: for tabs try https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/Tutorials/TabLayoutTutorial.cs

```
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.TabLayoutTutorial);

        TabHost.TabSpec spec;     // Resusable TabSpec for each tab  
        Intent intent;            // Reusable Intent for each tab  

        // Create an Intent to launch an Activity for the tab (to be reused)  
        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (ArtistsActivity));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        // Initialize a TabSpec for each tab and add it to the TabHost  
        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("artists");
        spec.SetIndicator ("Artists", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_artists));
        spec.SetContent (intent);
        TabHost.AddTab (spec);

        // Do the same for the other tabs  
        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (AlbumsActivity));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("albums");
        spec.SetIndicator ("Albums", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_artists));
        spec.SetContent (intent);
        TabHost.AddTab (spec);

        intent = new Intent (this, typeof (SongsActivity));
        intent.AddFlags (ActivityFlags.NewTask);

        spec = TabHost.NewTabSpec ("songs");
        spec.SetIndicator ("Songs", Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.ic_tab_artists));
        spec.SetContent (intent);
        TabHost.AddTab (spec);

        TabHost.CurrentTab = 2;
    }
```

Comment: I tried to follow your suggestion, but got following error. Please have a look at edited question.